# AttributeError: module 'yagmail' has no attribute 'SMTP'

Tags: python-3.x

Why do I get the below error?
I have imported `yagmail`. I have also tried with importing the `smtplib` module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Darsh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/class programes/project1/my_yagmail.py", line 1, in <module>
    from yagmail import *
  File "C:/Users/Darsh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/class programes/project1\yagmail.py", line 8, in <module>
    yag = yagmail.SMTP(user="dar*******@gmail.com", password="*******", host='smtp.gmail.com')
AttributeError: module 'yagmail' has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

Code:

```
import yagmail
receiver = "pat*******@gmail.com"
body = "Hello there from Yagmail"
filename = "c.pdf"

yag = yagmail(user="dar**********@gmail.com", password="**********", host='smtp.gmail.com')
yag.send(
    to=receiver,
    subject="Yagmail test with attachment",
    contents=body, 
    attachments=filename,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a script named "yagmail.py", I believe that the error is due to a namespace collision. My script was named the same thing, after renaming it the issue went away.

I saw a similar post on a different page in a different language that solved it (yay Google Translate!).